# jQuery Pass Parameters to iFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-selectors

I have several dropdown lists comprising of several checkboxes. I have an iFrame.

What I would like is when I choose whatever options I need to, when I click a "refresh" button/link, that the values get passed to the iFrame as parameters and for that iFrame to be refreshed

So for example let's say I have two dropdowns (**dropdownA** and **dropdownB**). The URL of the iFrame to be **www.report.com/reportone**.

**dropdownA** has the values **1,2,3** and **dropdownB** has the values **A,B,C**.

Let's say I choose **1,2** and **B,C** and click refresh, the iFrame should then loads this **report.com/reportone?dropdownA=1&dropdownA=2&dropdownB=B&dropdownB=C**

How do I go about setting this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may help you:

```
var params = "";
$("#dropdownA option:selected").each(function () {
    if (params.length == 0)
        params += "?";
    else
        params += "&";
    params += "dropdownA=" + $(this).val();
});

$("#dropdownB option:selected").each(function () {
    if (params.length == 0)
        params += "?";
    else
        params += "&";

    params += "dropdownB=" + $(this).val();
});
$('#your_iframe_id').attr("src", "report.com/reportone" + params);
```